# how can I install package to the wwwroot in mvc core 2

Tags: npm, asp.net-core, gulp, asp.net-core-mvc, bower

Recently I Installed the VS 2017 Which Contains Asp.net mvc core 2

but there is a very confusion problems there!

that is how can i Install a  new package into the wwwroot so:

_ Im using bower but supporting is end of and can not find out bower.json in the project>> new item after config it using npm . I installed it using npm but still can not find( .bowerrc file under bower.json.) to set the directory:

[So-called valid document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-gulp?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

_with gulp and grunt : end of supporting gulp too and can not find gulpfile.js in the project>>new Item after configure it using npm

please heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeelp me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50081423/240564

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Library Manager](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/04/17/library-manager-client-side-content-manager-for-web-apps/):

> Library Manager (“LibMan” for short) is Visual Studio’s experimental
>   client-side library acquisition tool. It provides a lightweight,
>   simple mechanism that helps users find and fetch library files from an
>   external source (such as CDNJS) and place them in your project.

Comment: the Client-side content manager is not showin in my project and i try to add it using this tools : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.Client-SideLibraryInstaller but while installing this error log was occure: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.

Comment: @Persiax, yes, for now it's only in VS Preview, which I use myself, but will be available soon in standard version.